# how to store and reference large amount of data in c++

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I am using a vector of strings in order to store some data in memory. Database is not an option. More precisely an array of vector of strings. A simple scenario: I need to store the names of people living in 256 cities.

Example

```
NewYork: John, Bod, ...
London: Jim, Bill...
```

for this requirement I used

```
vector<std::string> city[256];
```

A new requirement came to create a new "class Person" that will hold more data per item

```
class person {
 string name;
 string surname;
 string email;
 int age;
};
```

I am addressing this issue in order to find the optimal way to store and shared those data.

```
vector<class person> city[256];
```

Obviously is better to use a pointer to objects. does shared_ptr applies here? We have TR1
installed in the system but we cannot use boost libs.

Comment: "I need to store the surnames of 256 cities": 'please given an example of a city that has a forename and a surname.

Comment: Is really 256 cities "large amount of data"?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: New York? ;)

Comment: There is at least one city with patronymic in Russia ;-)

Comment: Do you have just a single, global instance of this data, or do you need to pass it around and manipulate it?

Comment: @Kerrek SN pass around and manipulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++11 and only need a single, global version of this data, you could use a data structure like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

typedef std::unordered_multiset<std::string> name_set;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, name_set> city_map;

city_map city_db {
  { "Moscow", { "Ivan", "Igor", "Vladimir" } },
  { "Madrid", { "Julio", "Pedro", "Sanchez" } },
  { "Munich", { "Sepp", "Huber", "Maier" } }
};

int main()
{
  return city_db["Munich"].size(); // just as an example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cities, persons.. time to consider a database.

Comment: DB is not an option. I updated my question. I need those data in process memory

Comment: @cateo: You don't need to have external server for the database, you know. Pure in-process databases exist, too.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a vector of vectors? or a list of vectors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared_ptr, or a native pointer, or store as value.  It depends.  Do you want the quickest look ups?  Do you want to save on memory?  Do you want data in contiguous memory?  Do you want to support threading?  There is no general correct answer.
256 objects is not a huge amount of data.

Comment: I updated my question. I need 256 vectors. Each vector can grow... DB is not an option and we use threads.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's so obvious that pointers are better. Yes, you can store `shared_ptr` in collection, though depending on how you access the data you may also prefer to use `list` or `map` instead.